# How to program the Robotdyn Mega 2560 PRO MINI?

Tags: arduino-mega, ftdi, atmega2560

I want to program the Robotdyn Mega 2560 PRO MINI which has no USB port.

How do I connect the pins to an FTDI?

Which setting do I have to use in the Arduino IDE?

Answer (score 1):

Connect the Arduino to the FTDI in the following way:

- FTDI - Arduino
- VCC - VCC
- GND - GND
- RX - TXD
- TX - RXD
- DTR - 100nf capacitor - RST
- CTS is not connected

Use the following settings in the Arduino IDE

- Board: Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega 2560
- Processor: ATMega2560 (Mega 2560)

[image: Arduino with FTDI]

The image shows the Arduino with colored connectors and with 4 extra rows of connectors. These are not part of the original Arduino. I added them to make it easy to connect lots of I2C devices for testing.